# How to create a BQ-schema from XSD

Tags: json, xml, google-bigquery

I need some guidance on how to proceed with a problem.
Our integration team receives xml files which are converted to json and sent to pub/sub. We then ingest the json files (or are supposed to) into bigquery.

The problem is that the xml files do not include all possible objects or values all the time. So, I cant create a correct schema in bq to receive the json files. I got the xsd file with an extension file which gives me all possible objects but I don't know how to convert this to a correct bq schema. 
Do you have any suggestions on how to create a bq schema from xsd files? I was thinking that if I create an xml file with dummy data (including all objects and more than one object when creating repeated objects) with help of the xsd maybe that xml file may be converted to json and then use the auto-schema detection of bq. 
Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Cris

Answer (score 0):

If you have the XSD schema files, you can convert these to a valid JSON schema. There are a few [tools](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/json-schema/mS0zP5nqGDo) that can help you to accomplish this.

Keep in mind that the tools are for general purposes and not for the particular case of BigQuery, so you'll have to tune the result to get a valid JSON schema. For this check the [components](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas#schema_components) of a BigQuery schema, and for quick reference the [sample](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas#creating_a_json_schema_file) provided in the documentation.